# sourceCpp() fail to source this file

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

when compiling this file, warn "invalid conversion ... const int". Can someone tell what is wrong and how to fixit. thanks.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
//[[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector ats(SEXP p, SEXP rolsd, SEXP sig, SEXP b)
{
  Rcpp::NumericVector loc_p(p);
  Rcpp::NumericVector loc_rolsd(rolsd);
  Rcpp::IntegerVector signal(sig);
  int n=loc_p.size();
  int m=signal.size();
  float bb = Rcpp::as<float>(b);
  Rcpp::IntegerVector result[m];
  for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
  { 
    int i=0;
    float  ma=loc_p[j];
    while(loc_p[i+signal[j]] >= (1-loc_rolsd[i+signal[j]]*bb)*ma & i<=n-signal[j])
    {
      i=i+1;
      if(ma < loc_p[i+signal[j]]) ma = loc_p[i+signal[j]];
    }
    result[j]=i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You are using `&` instead of `&&` in the `while()` statement. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Did you mean `Rcpp::IntegerVector result(m);` instead of `Rcpp::IntegerVector result[m];`

Comment: something wrong about the conversion

Comment: Did the error give you a line number.  Which line is it complaining on? If you are asking a question about an error, it is best to post the whole error text.

Comment: Please add all the details of the compiler's error message to your question.

Comment: Do check your while statement...

Answer (score 1):

Please check your while statement.

```
while(((loc_p[i+signal[j]]) >= ((1-loc_rolsd[i+signal[j]]*bb)*ma)) && (i<=n-signal[j]))
    {
      i=i+1;
      if(ma < loc_p[i+signal[j]])
         ma = loc_p[i+signal[j]];
    }
```

And I think you have to check this statement too.

`Rcpp::IntegerVector result[m];`

While declaration `array` need `Constant Value` So you need to
declare as

`Rcpp::IntegerVector result[10]; // where m should be any int const value`
Hope this will help you.